# ES6 Syntax Object Short Notation and Computed Properties

Tags: ecmascript-6

I am learning `react-native`. I came across this syntax of ES6

First Syntax

```
this.state = {
   refreshing: false,
};
```

Second Syntax

```
this.state = {[refreshing]: false};
```

Will it perform same task ? If these  line of code same task then what is the difference between Object Short Notation and Computed Properties

Comment: Will it perform at all?

Comment: @zeroflagL what ?

Comment: Does the second statement even run? It's not valid JavaScript.

Comment: As zeroflagL points out, the second is not valid syntax. `this.state = {["refreshing"]: false};` would be the equivalent using computed properties, but obviously redundant here.

Answer (score 0):

No. They are totally different:

```
const state = {
   refreshing: false,
};
console.log(state); // { refreshing: false }
```

In your second example:

```
const state = {[refreshing]: false};
// Error: refreshing is not defined
```

This is because computed properties look for a variable called `refreshing` within the accessible scope. For example:

```
const refreshing = "example";
const state = { [refreshing]: false };
console.log(state); // { example: false }
```

So the equivalent to your first example in computed property syntax would be:

```
const key = "refreshing";
const state = {[key]: false};
console.log(state); // { refreshing: false }
```

But you would only use this if you don't know `key` ahead of time.

Comment: refreshing is const variable in my case also then both are same ? what do you mean of "But you would only use this if you don't know key ahead of time."